# Probability, bayes theorem

Tags: probability, bayes-theorem

Good day, hi, would like to ask a math question as follows:

${P(Y_5 = 0 | Y_2 = 0, Y_3 = 1) = \sum_{Y_1, Y_4, Y_6}P(Y_5 = 0, Y_1, Y_4, Y_6| Y_2 = 0, Y_3 = 1)}$

Applying ${P(A|B) = \cfrac{P(A,B)}{P(B)}}$

${\cfrac{= \sum_{Y_1, Y_4, Y_6}P(Y_5 = 0, Y_1, Y_4, Y_6, Y_2 = 0, Y_3 = 1)}{?}}$

What's the denominator?

Please, help out, deadline is around the corner T____T

Comment: is it i can skip ${P(Y_5 = 0 | Y_2 = 0, Y_3 = 1) = \sum_{Y_1, Y_4, Y_6}P(Y_5 = 0, Y_1, Y_4, Y_6| Y_2 = 0, Y_3 = 1)}$

and apply ${P(A|B) = \cfrac{P(A,B)}{P(B)}}$ straightly to become

${P(Y_5 = 0 | Y_2 = 0, Y_3 = 1) = \cfrac{\sum_{Y_1, Y_4, Y_6}P(Y_5 = 0, Y_1, Y_4, Y_6, Y_2 = 0, Y_3 = 1)}{\sum_{Y_1, Y_4, Y_5, Y_6}P(Y_5, Y_1, Y_4, Y_6, Y_2 = 0, Y_3 = 1)}}$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The denominator is just $P(Y_2=0,Y_3=1)$ since this is the part you are conditioning on.  The $A$ in your equation is the event $[Y_5=0,Y_1,Y_4,Y_6]$ and your $B$ is: $[Y_2=0,Y_3=1]$.  It is the same for each summand, does this make sense?

Comment: ah i see, yeah, it does make sense to me ,thanks a million!!